# plotting histogram

Tags: c

I'm writing a function to plot a histogram but I'm stuck with a problem.
This is the code

```
void plotHist(int num, regression *r, histData *h)
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i< h->numHist; i++)
   {
       printf("%2f\t|", h->hist[i].xValue) ;
           for ( j = 0 ; j < h->hist[i].yFrequency/5; j ++)
           {
               printf("*");

           }


        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

The result I get on screen is:

```
                -199.422 |  
                -142.232 |****
                -98.232  |******
                -21.32   |***********
                 43.424  |****************
                 58.234  |***************
                 92.123  |*********
                 189.5   |****
```

The problem is that I have to add another array to this histogram by "o" letters which I don't know how to do.
The result should be like this:

```
        -199.422 |  o
        -142.232 |****o
        -98.232  |******o
        -21.32   |********o**
        43.424   |**********o*****
        58.234   |********o******
        92.123   |******o**
        189.5    |****o
```

Comment: What value does an "o" correspond to ?

Comment: "o "correspond to value of another array name gaussY[]

Answer (score 2):

Do not print the histogram immediately with printf. Instead, figure out where all the data points will be before you do the printing. This way, you won't have to check every your data time you print a character AND the second array won't have to be within the histogram's painted region.